# Unable to access bucket storage files from R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio, google-cloud-platform, rstudio-server

I have installed R-studio on my Google cloud platform compute instance.
By default working directory on R-studio is:

/home/rstudio

Then I mounted a cloud storage bucket on my compute instance. Mounted image path is:

/mnt/gcs-bucket

But when I try to read from files located in this directory on r studio using:

```
r<-read.csv("/mnt/gcs-bucket/trainS.csv")
```

I get following error

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '/mnt/gcs-bucket/trainS.csv': Permission denied
```

How can I give permissions on files so that they are accessible from R-Studio.
I have already tried:

```
chmod 777 /mnt/gcs-bucket/trainS.csv
```

But I still get the same error.

Reading file on R works just fine.
In R-Studio I an unable change my working directory:

```
setwd("/mnt/gcs-bucket")
Error in setwd("/mnt/gcs-bucket") : cannot change working directory
```

Comment: You could try `sudo chown rstudio:rstudio /mnt/gcs-bucket/`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about how to fix the issue with your approach, but here are 2 different approaches to access files from google cloud storage to your R-studio either in GCE or locally that I find pretty easy:

1. (not secure, but quite convenient) Enable the "share public" in google cloud storage interface,

[image: Enable the "share public"]

then access the file from that public link:

```
read.csv("https://storage.googleapis.com/your-bucket-name/testfile.csv")
```

If it's a large file, fread() from data.table will be much quicker to load and it gives you an indication of the loading progress(speed, eta):

```
library(data.table)
fread("https://storage.googleapis.com/your-bucket-name/testfile.csv")
```

2. Or you can use the [googleCloudStorageR](https://github.com/cloudyr/googleCloudStorageR) package to download/upload files from R-studio to GCS.